# how to support css variables in styled-components?

Tags: styled-components

I am using NextJS and in `IE11` the layout is broken.
I have colors like `:root {--color:#000}` in my css file.

The issue is that IE doesn't support CSS variables how can I solve that

I tried to use `postcss` with `styled-component` but it didn't work.